# Visual Studio sets all ImageAssets to Visible = false

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, assets

I have a Xamarin project which targets iOS and Android. I mainly develop on Windows with Visual Studio. The project is version controlled with git.

Recently, I used a Mac to build and deploy the iOS app and for this, I added icon sets (App Icon and Launch Screen) under `Resources/Media.xcassets`. After committing these changes to git and pulling them on the Windows machine, and after opening up Visual Studio, the `Resources/Media.xcassets` entry doesn't show up in the Solution Explorer.

This would not be a problem per se - but the `csproj` file got modified by VS like the following (so basically the image assets got marked invisible):

```
   <ItemGroup>
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Contents.json" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@1x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@2x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@3x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@1x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@2x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@3x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@1x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@2x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@3x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-60x60@2x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-60x60@3x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-76x76@1x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-76x76@2x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Contents.json" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default%402x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default-568h%402x.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default-Portrait.png" />
-    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default-Portrait%402x.png" />
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Contents.json">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@1x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@2x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@3x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@1x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@2x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@3x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@1x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@2x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@3x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-60x60@2x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-60x60@3x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-76x76@1x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-76x76@2x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Contents.json">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default%402x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default-568h%402x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default-Portrait.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
+    <ImageAsset Include="Resources\Media.xcassets\LaunchImage.launchimage\Default-Portrait%402x.png">
+      <Visible>false</Visible>
+    </ImageAsset>
   </ItemGroup>
```

I tried closing VS, reverting those changes to the project file and opened up VS again. As soon as VS loads the project, it modifies the `csproj` file again like above.

I have not the slightest idea of what is going on, nor how to avoid this. I do not need to see the resource files under Windows, however, I do not want to commit a change like this under version control, since I guess that this would make the assets disappear on my Mac, too...

So how can I avoid that?

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 and that's a Xamarin Forms 2 project (in case that matters).

Comment: Did you find any answer?

Comment: I had the same problem, but the iOS project Resource folder did not show the icons in VS for Mac anyway. I guess VS for Mac ignores them by default but VS for Windows needs it explicitly ignored. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. In any case, it should not affect your build or the app Icon itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug with either the Xamarin Forms version or your VS Community version, I'd say upgrade to latest (or move to VS Community '19) and rebuild your project